# Cannot Update Summary Task Form in infopath

Tags: infopath, custom-form, form

I am trying to customize the forms used to add and update Summary Tasks in a Task List in SharePoint 2010.   When I try to open the form in InfoPath I get an error 'Customizing the form for this content type is not supported.'  I have Already made sure the content type is NOT read only, which is the only suggestion I can find and it has no effect whatsoever.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately , summery task in SharePoint List and also Project Center in PWA can't be updated because it's a cumulative task to all child tasks that it calculated automatically based on build-in formula.